# Accessing shared data from a signal handler

Tags: multithreading, pthreads, multiprocessing, semaphore

I want to know if it is a good idea to access shared data from a signal handler. I mean consider the scenario of multi process system and multithreaded system with a single process. In multi process system, lets say I have the processes handle a particular signal and update certain shared variable or memory by the processes. Can I do that from the signal handler itself.

However, in the case of threads using pthreads, I don't think it is doable. http://maxim.int.ru/bookshelf/PthreadsProgram/htm/r_40.html. As given in this article, they have mentioned that it is not asynchronous signal safe and have suggested to use sigwait for that. I am not why it is not asynchronous signal safe. I mean lets say, I handle a signal by a thread and is in the signal handler routing. I acquire a lock on the shared memory to update it. In the mean time another signal of the same type arrives and another thread responsible for handling it executes the signal handler again. Here the signal handler is same for the process but it is called multiple time. The second time around, it cannot see the lock and updates/overrides the data. Is this the issue with multithreaded signal handlers using shared data.

I am a bit confused, in multi process systems, I have a copy of the signal handler for each process. But in multithreaded system, there is a single copy of the signal handler used by the multiple threads isn't it. So when multiple signals of the same type arrives and we have two threads that are responsible for handling it try to handle it, then both of them will try to execute the same piece of handler code? How does it all fit in?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I read through the article that you reference and found some interesting information in the ***"Threads in Signal Handlers"*** section. In that section, you'll see that they have a list of Posix function calls that can be made from within signal handlers. Then soon after that list, they mention the following:

> But where are the Pthreads calls? They're not in either of these
>   lists! In fact, the Pthreads standard specifies that the behavior of
>   all Pthreads functions is undefined when the function is called from a
>   signal handler. If your handler needs to manipulate data that is
>   shared with other threads≈buffers, flags, or state variables≈it's out
>   of luck. The Pthreads mutex and condition variable synchronization
>   calls are off limits.

Notice the last sentence: "Pthreads mutex and condition variable synchronization calls are off limits"

The aforementioned functions that can be called from a signal handler are described as follows:

> These functions have a special property known as reentrancy that
>   allows a process to have multiple calls to these functions in progress
>   at the same time.

The pthread synchronization functions dont have the special property known as reentrancy, so I imagine that if these functions (pthread_mutex_lock() for instance) are interrupted by an arriving signal, then the behavior is not "safe".

Imagine that your application calls `pthread_mutex_lock(&theMutex)` and at exactly that moment (that is, while in the pthread_mutex_lock() function) a signal arrives. If the signal handler also calls `pthread_mutex_lock(&theMutex)`, the previous pthread call may not have terminated, so it cant be guaranteed which call to pthread_mutex_lock() will get the lock. So the resulting behavior will be undefined/undeterministic.

I would imagine that the call to sigwait() from a particular thread would guarantee that no important, `non-reentrancy` function calls may get interrupted, thus allowing calls to the pthread synchronization functions to be "safe".

Comment: How would you imagine the standard case of `pthread_mutex_lock()` being called at the same time by multiple threads working out? :)
(given this use case is exactly why we have mutexes, that is; smth begs for clarification here, seems)

Comment: @mlvljr: That's different - with signals, it might be the *same* thread calling `pthread_mutex_lock` twice at the same time (well not quite the same time, but one call partially run when another is started in a signal handler).

Comment: Also, what if that thread *already owns* the mutex when a signal is received causing it to try to acquire the mutex (excluding recursive mutexes).